# Background not scaling or repeating on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The header on my site is scaling strangely when viewed on mobile.

I have a background color with white text and am using Bootstrap along with my own css to style it. Whenever loaded on a smartphone or as a phone in Chrome Dev Tools two issues occur.

1. The page does not scale to meet the width of the phone and forces a scroll bar.
2. When you scroll, anything that would be displayed is not there. I'm pretty sure this is due to the background color not extending and the text being white.

How can I get the page to scale to mobile and have the background color extend across the screen.

I've tried variations of

```
margin: 0%
padding: 0%
```

and

```
width: 100%
height: 100%
overflow-x: hidden;
```

without luck.

I've also changed the font of the header to a responsive value (200%) as opposed to 36px but that also doesn't do the trick.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/4.1.1/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="header text-center col-sm-12">
    <h1>LoremIpsumLoremdolorsitamet.com</h1>
        <div class="subpages text-center">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a>  </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.header{
    font-family: 'bungee shade', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 3%;
    background-color: #384047;
    color: white;
    padding: 2%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;

}
.header .h1, .header h1 {
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how or why but now having the following in the css seems to resolve it on an actual phone but not in Chrome Dev Tools.

```
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow-x: inherit;
```